# Find database location of a table

Tags: sql

I have several databases in my SQL Server 2008. And I forgot where some tables from, so I need to ask if there's a such query that finds the database location of a certain table?

I need something goes like this:

```
SELECT DATABASE_NAME FROM SQLSERVER WHERE TABLE= "TBL_PRODUCTS"
```

Addition:
   Now, i need to know the database location of certain Views and Stored Procedures

Something like this:

```
SELECT DATABASE_NAME FROM SQLSERVER WHERE VIEW= "VW_PRODUCTS"

SELECT DATABASE_NAME FROM SQLSERVER WHERE StoredProcedure= "SP_PRODUCTS"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
Use Master
Go

    select 
    'select '''+CAST(name as varchar(200))+''' from '+CAST(name as varchar(200))+'.sys.tables where name = yourTableName' 
    from sysdatabases
```

replacing  `yourTableName` with the name of your table, with `' '`

You will get `selects`; then run those and will get the results.
If there are more than 100 `databases`, use `results to text`, because to grid, you will only get 100 `selects` maximum

Comment: thanks! this is pretty good answer as well but i have to consider the solution of Dor Cohen, for it is a click away to the answers i need.

Answer (score 3):

The following procedure will do the job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase
@TableName VARCHAR(256)
AS
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR
SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (DBName VARCHAR(256),
SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
TableName VARCHAR(256))
OPEN @getDBName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + ';
INSERT INTO #TmpTable
SELECT '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE ''%' + @TableName + '%'''
EXEC (@varSQL)
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE @getDBName
DEALLOCATE @getDBName
SELECT *
FROM #TmpTable
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
GO
EXEC usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase 'Address'
GO
```

The result would look like that:

[image: Result Table]

[Source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/29/sql-server-find-table-in-every-database-of-sql-server/)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't exactly return the name of the database location of a certain table.

Comment: Hi there, how about looking for database location of views and stored procedures? How will it be?